# How can Envelope Rejection Sampling be used to generate samples from a posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, monte-carlo, posterior, rejection-sampling

Say we have two independent variables:
$X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ but these cannot be observed directly.
Instead, we can observe $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma_r^2)$ is the observational noise.

Now, assuming $R$ is given a value, say $r$, how can envelope rejection sampling then be used to generate samples from the posterior distribution $p(x,y|r)$, considering that $p(r)$ is unknown?